# display data as drop down which is derived from database

Tags: mysql

I have a menu bar. It has many main categories and sub categories stored in the database. I derived that data using the code below:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <?php while($rowmain = mysql_fetch_array($resultmain)):;?>
    <?php echo "<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>$rowmain[0]<b class='caret'></b></a>" ?>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="multi-gd-img">
    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
    <h6>All Groceries</h6>
        <li><a href='groceries.php'><?php echo "$rowmain[1]"?></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </ul>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</li>
```

mysql code

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("../database/connection.php");

$main="SELECT t1.name,x from maincatagory t1 LEFT JOIN(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) as x,mainID from subcatagory GROUP by mainID) t2 on t1.mainID = t2.mainID";
$resultmain=mysql_query($main);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$countmain=mysql_num_rows($resultmain);

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

But my problem is that sub categories don't display as a list, they're displaied in the same line:

```
**Main**               **Sub**
Alcohol                 BEER
Baby Care               soap , toy
Chilled&Frozen Food     chicken,egg
Fresh Halal Meats       chicken,pizza
Fruits And Vegetables   ale,orange
Grocery                 Savoury ingredients ,Soups,Meals,Canned vegetables...
Gift&Greeting Cards     birthdaycard, valantine card
Household               spoon,knife
Medicine                panadol,priton,amoxixiline
Soft Drinks             cococola,fanta,pepsi
```

I expected the output table to be:

```
**Main**               **Sub**
Alcohol                 BEER
Baby Care               soap
                        toy
Chilled&Frozen Food     chicken
                        egg
Fresh Halal Meats       chicken
                        pizza
Fruits And Vegetables   apple
                        orange
Grocery                 Savory ingredients
                        Soups
                        Meals
                        vegetables...
Gift&Greeting Cards     birthday card
                        valentine card
Household               spoon
                        knife
Medicine                panadol 
                        priton
                        amoxiciline
Soft Drinks             pepsi
                        cococola
                        fanta
```

Comment: There are three separate parts involved, SQL, PHP and HTML. Which of them is giving you problems? Please edit your question and restrict it to preferably one, at most two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check sub is not null. 
if it is not null then explode by comma and foreach your exploded data.

Comment: ya I not yet add all sub, still now I add one sub category for one main category

Comment: sir could you please explain more